# Entity Framework - Mapped property will not populate, despite being retrieved by SQL

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first, fluent-interface

I'm trying to add a new sub-entity, product component `ProductRevComp` to an existing entity `ProductRev`. However when I retrieve an instance of the ProductRev class, the Comps collection is never populated (even when explicitly `Including()` it). I *BELIEVE* I have mapped everything correctly, but it has taken more fiddling than I want and this is the most likely place for a mistake to be hiding. However profiling the SQL statements show the relevent columns are being populated with the correct data.

Checking `db.ProductRevComps` (i.e. the `DbSet` of all my comps) shows the records can be loaded, and that mapping is working as expected.

Mappings:

```
    public class ProductRevConfiguration : EntityTypeConfiguration<ProductRev>
    {
        public ProductRevConfiguration()
        {
            HasKey(p => p.ProductRevId);
            HasMany(p => p.Comps).WithRequired().HasForeignKey(p => p.ParentProductRevId);
            Ignore(p => p.ProgrammedParts);
        }
    }

    public class ProductRevCompConfiguration : EntityTypeConfiguration<ProductRevComp>
    {
        public ProductRevCompConfiguration()
        {
            HasKey(p => new { p.ParentProductRevId, p.CompProductRevId });
            HasRequired(p => p.ParentProductRev).WithMany().HasForeignKey(p => p.ParentProductRevId);
            HasRequired(p => p.CompProductRev).WithMany().HasForeignKey(p => p.CompProductRevId);
        }
    }
```

Product entity (amazingly simplified):

```
public class ProductRev
{
    public string ProductRevId { get; set; }
    public virtual List<ProductRevComp> Comps { get; set; }
    public virtual List<ProductRevComp> ProgrammedParts { get { return Comps; } }//Will be filtered once I get this working

    public ProductRev() { }
}
```

Comp entity:

```
public class ProductRevComp
{
    public string ParentProductRevId { get; set; }
    public virtual ProductRev ParentProductRev { get; set; }

    public string CompProductRevId { get; set; }
    public virtual ProductRev CompProductRev { get; set; }

    public int CompTypeValue { get; set; }
    public ProductRevCompType CompType
    {
        get { return (ProductRevCompType)CompTypeValue; }
        set { CompTypeValue = (int)value; }
    }

    public enum ProductRevCompType { ProgrammedPart = 1 };

    public ProductRevComp() { }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return base.ToString();
    }

}
```

Removing the extra prog parts collection doesn't change anything.

How can I get the ProductRev entity to populate the Comps property without resorting to a manual DB hit?

(Must run as the office is closing and I don't have a key - I hope I have included all details, please comment if anything is missing.)

Comment: You need to make your `ProductRev` property `virtual` to enable lazy/eager loading, that will fix your problem

Comment: D'oh. That's definitely something I missed that I normally do (and a very silly to boot) - will try ASAP tomorrow. But it was still definitely attempting to map those properties without the `virtual` - I had several issues earlier caused by these mappings, sans `virtual`. So (just out of curiosity) why is the virtual required if its still mapped without it assuming I don't care if it is lazy loaded?

Comment: Unfortunately this did not fix the problem.